# How to create a grouped select box using simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, simple-form

I'm using simple_form gem for creating Rails forms.
http://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

All is great, except how do I create a grouped select box? Can't find it in the docs or by google-ing.

Comment: grouped select box has been added to simple_form 2.0.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The question is old but it's the top result for "simple_form grouped select" google search anyway so I figured the next reader might benefit from a few creative ways to create these with the latest simple_form (taken from tests, which are always the best documentation indeed)

```
<%= f.input :author,
 :as => :grouped_select,
 :collection => [['Authors', ['Jose', 'Carlos']], ['General', ['Bob', 'John']]],
 :group_method => :last %>

<%= f.input :author,
 :as => :grouped_select,
 :collection => Proc.new { [['Authors', ['Jose', 'Carlos']], ['General', ['Bob', 'John']]] },
 :group_method => :last %>

<%= f.input :author,
 :as => :grouped_select,
 :collection => { ['Jose', 'Carlos'] => 'Authors' },
 :group_method => :first,
 :group_label_method => :last %>

<%= f.input :author,
 :as => :grouped_select,
 :collection => { 'Authors' => ['Jose', 'Carlos'] },
 :group_method => :last,
 :label_method => :upcase,
 :value_method => :downcase %>
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks for providing several different solutions. I hope he accepts your answer.

Comment: I'm assuming this is for simple_form 2.0+ ? Or would this work with older simple_form like I tried using back in 2010.

Comment: Cash-money! The first solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you please explain why you're using :first as group_method? I'm trying to wrap my mind around it...

Comment: This stumped me for a moment, so here's my take on it. You can pass in any object as a collection. Hash, array, AR object etc. It needs to be iteratable. Each 'thing' in it becomes a group object. The 'group label method' is called on this group object, what it gets back is used as the group label. 'group method' is also called on the group object, and what comes back is the value object. The value object needs to be iteratable. Simple Form cycles through it, calling 'label method' and 'value method' on each element. This gives us the label and value for each select option. Easy, huh?

Comment: So the `:group_method` option is meant to designate the method that must be called in order to find/return the list of options for the group. Then, `:label_method` and `:value_method` further designate the methods that must be called on the result of the `:group_method` call in order to find/return the text that is shown to the user and the value of the option, when selected, respectively.

Comment: What if you need to have grouped options, plus some non grouped options?

Comment: Example using models instead of strings: `f.input :tab_id, as: :grouped_select, collection: Tab.all.group_by(&:type), group_method: :last`

Answer (score 9):

If you hava two models which are category, subcategory as follows:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
    has_many :subcategories
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :products
end
```

Then you can use

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @yourmodel] do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :subcategory_id, collection: Category.all, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :subcategories, prompt: "Select One" %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

which result like this:

```
<div class="form-group grouped_select optional yourmodel_subcategory_id">
    <label class="grouped_select optional control-label" for="yourmodel_subcategory_id">Subcategory</label>
    <select class="grouped_select optional form-control" id="yourmodel_subcategory_id" name="yourmodel[subcategory_id]">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <optgroup label="Your 1st Category">
        <option value="This subcategory id">one subcategory belongs to Your 1st Category</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Your 2nd Category">
        <option value="This subcategory id">one subcategory belongs to Your 2nd Category</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh.. Goodness. You sir, are a wonder. I've just spent the last hour boshing something together to get an array, of arrays, within arrays.. as per the selected answer. I then saw your explanation, and I repeated the same in 20 seconds. Thank you so much. I had this completely backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Only sane way I've found to create grouped select boxes is to use the select helper passing in a [grouped_options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/option_groups_from_collection_for_select) which *does* take a selected_key parameter for the choices argument (so you can ensure the one thats set in your model actually gets selected).  You'll see the full call below.  Sorry if its confusing.

```
-# @answer is the model instance passed into simple_form_for/form_for
select(@answer.class.to_s.underscore, :question_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@categories, 'questions.order(:display_order)', :name, :id, :question, @answer.question_id))
```

If there's a better way to do this that selects the proper value, I'm all ears as well.

**tl;dr:** nope not seeing any way with either form_for or simple_form_for to create grouped selects, the above should help at least.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look into the tests as well.
If you want to pass a **different value** to the option tag, use the following to pass it to the collection:

```
Agent = Struct.new(:id, :name)
agents = [["First", []], ["Second", [Agent.new(7, 'Bond'), Agent.new(47, 'Hitman')]]]
```

see https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/test/inputs/grouped_collection_select_input_test.rb