# Rails using join table to display grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to setup a Rails 4 form to display all of the different store branches in a `collection_select`, followed by a `grouped_collection_select` displaying all of the possible combinations of storage types for each branch. I then want to filter out the storage types not available at a certain branch using CoffeeScript, as shown in [Railscasts #88](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) (this is not an issue)

However, I can't figure out how to populate the grouped select pre-filtering. I need to go through the joining table `StorageTypeBranch` to find the storage types available at each branch.

My models:

```
class StorageType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :storage_type_branches
  has_many :branches, through: :storage_type_branches
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :storage_type_branches
  has_many :storage_types, through: :storage_type_branches
end

# Joining table
class StorageTypeBranch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :storage_type
  belongs_to :branch
end
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @branches = Branch.where(is_active: true).order(:name)

  # Doesn't work because it has to be called on one instance of the model. 
  # What should this be?
  @storage_types = @branches.storage_types.all
end
```

View:

```
<%= f.label :branch_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :branch_id, @branches, :id, :name, prompt: '<--- Select a Branch --->' %>
<br/>
<%= f.label :storage_type_id %>
# Where I want the grouped select to be
<%= f.grouped_collection_select @storage_types %>
```

The end result I'm looking to achieve:

[image: Final Result]

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all branch types for the list of branches:

```
@storage_types = @branches.flat_map{|branch| branch.storage_types}.uniq # Array
```

If you want them for each branch:

```
@storage_types = Hash[@branches.map{|branch| [branch, branch.storage_types]}] 
# {branch1 => [storage_typeA, storage_typeB], branch2 => [storage_typeC, storageTypeE]}
```

You can then group the collection with something like:

```
<%= f.input :storage_types, :as => :grouped_select, :collection =>  @storage_types, :group_method => :first, :group_label_method => :last %>
```

For more alternative see: [simple_form: how to create a grouped select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037537/simple-form-how-to-create-a-grouped-select-box)

Comment: Thanks for the response Martin. The second answer is what I'm looking to achieve. I'm still struggling to implement this in a grouped select though. Could you help with this?

Also, when I call `.inspect` on `@storage_types` (the second answer), nothing is returned, but when I remove the `Hash.new`, I can see the correct results. Do you know why?

Comment: My bad, my syntax was not correct. I'll update the code. The general idea is to create an Hash with your branches as key and storage types as value, so you can retrieve them easily

Comment: Edited the code (correct syntax is Hash[] and not Hash.new() as shown before).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can see the results now.

Last question, do you know how I can get the grouped select to now work using `@storage_types` like the pic in the OP?

Comment: Updated. If this helped, don't forget to +1 & approve