# Rails: How to set value with grouped_select in simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I refer to [the top voted answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037537/simple-form-how-to-create-a-grouped-select-box) to create grouped select box.

What I'd like to do is to set the value as integer instead of the name listed.

For example,I'd like to set as followings;

```
<optgroup label="Transportation">
  <option value="1">bus</option>
  <option value="2">taxi</option>
  <option value="3">train</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Eat/Drink">
  <option value="11">meal</option>
  <option value="12">tea</option>
</optgroup>
```

instead of

```
<optgroup label="Transportation">
  <option value="bus">bus</option>
  <option value="taxi">taxi</option>
  <option value="train">train</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Eat/Drink">
  <option value="meal">meal</option>
  <option value="tea">tea</option>
</optgroup>
```

My view is as below.

```
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :days, @days do |d| %>

        <%= d.simple_fields_for :events do |e| %>

          <span class="form-inline">
            <p>
              <%= e.input :category, 
                :as => :grouped_select, 
                collection: [["Transportation", ["bus", "taxi", "train" ]],["Eat/Drink", ["meal", "tea/cafe"]]], 
                :group_method => :last, 
                label: false 
              %>
            </p>
          </span>
          <%= e.input :title, label: false %>

        <% end %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to set the value by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass texts with separate values to the `grouped_select` input as **two-element arrays** instead of just the values:

```
<%= e.input :category, 
            :as => :grouped_select, 
            collection: [["Transportation", [["bus", 1], ["taxi", 2], ["train", 3]]],
                         ["Eat/Drink", [["meal", 11], ["tea/cafe", 12]]]], 
            :group_method => :last, 
            label: false 
          %>
```

The first element is the text in the select, the second element is the value that will be passed in the `params` upon submit.

The code above produces the following html:

```
<select class="grouped_select optional" name="...">
  <option value=""></option>
  <optgroup label="Transportation">
    <option value="1">bus</option>
    <option value="2">taxi</option>
    <option value="3">train</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Eat/Drink">
    <option value="10">meal</option>
    <option value="11">tea/cafe</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

You can actually use any style (e.g. with hashes instead of 2-element arrays) supported by the `options_for_select` helper, see the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @BoraMa. It works! And thank you for your link for documentation, it's useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but it's the top result for "simple_form grouped select" google search anyway so I figured the next reader might benefit from a few creative ways to create these with the latest simple_form (taken from tests, which are always the best documentation indeed)

```
<%= f.input :author,
 :as => :grouped_select,
 :collection => [['Authors', ['Jose', 'Carlos']], ['General', ['Bob', 'John']]],
 :group_method => :last %>

<%= f.input :author,
 :as => :grouped_select,
 :collection => Proc.new { [['Authors', ['Jose', 'Carlos']], ['General', ['Bob', 'John']]] },
 :group_method => :last %>

<%= f.input :author,
 :as => :grouped_select,
 :collection => { ['Jose', 'Carlos'] => 'Authors' },
 :group_method => :first,
 :group_label_method => :last %>

<%= f.input :author,
 :as => :grouped_select,
 :collection => { 'Authors' => ['Jose', 'Carlos'] },
 :group_method => :last,
 :label_method => :upcase,
 :value_method => :downcase %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, @Bharat soni. I referred [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037537/simple-form-how-to-create-a-grouped-select-box) as I mentioned at the top of my question. It would be appreciated if you could give me how to set `option value`.