# Ruby on Rails Categorization Via Simple_Form collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

Is what I am doing even practical or is there a much easier way to implement this category/sub-category system?

**My categorization System**

I have an app that has a `posts` table that will be organized by a `blog_categories` table. This categorization has main categories and sub-categories. `blog_categories` with `parent_id` as `NULL` are the main categories. sub-categories link to the main via a `:string` with the main's `:name`.

**Assigning the categories to the post**

I was trying to implement this using `simple_form` and wanted to have the dropdown selector, divide the collection of sub-categories based on the main category. I ran into the problem of only showing the first item in each array when I tried to make an array of arrays:

```
<%= f.input :category_id, prompt: "Select Category", collection: [
["No-category"],
["All News","Audio Industry","Game Audio","Film Audio"],
["All Reviews","Software","Hardware"],
["All Interviews","Sound Designers","Game Developers","Voice Talent"],
["All Tutorials","Sound Design","Composition","Implementation","Voice Acting"]
], input_html: { class: "form-control center" } %>
```

**blog_category Modal**:

```
class BlogCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts

  # This is called a self referential relation. This is where records in a table may point to other records in the same table.
  has_many :sub_blog_categories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

**blog_categories Table:**

```
t.string "name"
t.string "parent_id"
```

**Post modal:** `belongs_to :blog_category`

**posts Table:** `t.string "category_id"`

1. Is there a different way of adding in groups/dividers in the dropdown?
2. Should I even be taking this approach in assinging sub-categories?
3. Will this even work when using main categories and sub categories?

Comment: I suppose you are looking for grouped options. Isn't it? Maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11032247/5239030) you can find some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to assigning the `category_id` based on the `BlogCategory.id` selected from its `:name` by using the following simple_form input:

```
<%= f.input :category_id, collection: BlogCategory.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id , input_html: { class: "form-control center" } %>
```

The `BlogCategory.all` pulls all of the categories that have been entered into the `blog_category` table.

The `label_method` pulls the `:name` of each item in the `blog_category` table.

The `value_method` assigns a value to all selections in the drop-down menu based on the `.id` of the respective fields `:name` from the `blog_category` table.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs for simple_form, it can do what you need:
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections

```
f.input :country_id, collection: @continents, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :countries
```

This normal functionality provided by the HTML select, so you're on the right track!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

In your case, I believe this is what you want:

```
f.input :post_id, collection: @categories, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :posts
```

Because you're going to provide a list of categories, and they have the association 'posts', which is the method you want to hit: `@categories.first.posts`

Comment: Would I just transfer the object `@categories` for instance, into my controller and `=` it to be the contents of my array?

Comment: @Jake You got it. I updated my answer to reflect your situation.

Comment: I've added @categories.first.posts = [array] in my posts controller outside of all of the methods (since all of the methods would use it?) and I got the error undefined method 'first' I'm not that advanced with Ruby so pardon my misconceptions if I have any.

Comment: Oops sorry. I was using the first for an example to see the first member of the collection.

Comment: f.input :post_id, collection: BlogCategory.all, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :posts Try this, it's the direct approach.

Comment: so use :post_id? This form is in my posts edit/create view. I was thinking about referencing to the correct category via `:category_id` but is this wrong?